# Why Java swing components failed to do typewriting effect

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I am using netbeans8 for doing my java projects.
Here is a java function that I create it to perform some typing effect.Program shows no error,and working good.

Any one can copy this function in your program and run it.and view the result.there you can see the actual problem..Is it my error or any thing else.
Here is my bit of code

```
private void type_writer_effect() {
        CERT[0]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";
        CERT[1]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";
        CERT[2]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";
        CERT[3]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";
        CERT[4]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";        
        CERT[5]="10101101 1010101 101010101101 011001";
                     //   Here simply i wrote an array named CERT[6]
                     // not an actual value.its just for testing

 int i=0;                                                       
 int j=0;
 jTextPane1.setText(" ");
    for(i=0;i<=5;i++) {                                                 

       for(j=0;j<=CERT[i].length()-1;j++) {
           // to display in console
           System.out.println(jTextPane1.getText()+String.valueOf(CERT[i].charAt(j)));

           // to display in jTextPane
           jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+String.valueOf(CERT[i].charAt(j))); 

           if(CERT[i].charAt(j) == ' ') {     
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(20);
                 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                  System.err.println(ex);}
            } else {
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(10);
                 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // System.err.println(ex);}
            }                                                    
        }                                                
     jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+"\n");
    }
}


private void jButton1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
  type_writer_effect();
}
```

The result getting in the **netbeans output panel** looks great and exactly like what I need.

```
// to display in console
       System.out.println(jTextPane1.getText()+String.valueOf(CERT[i].charAt(j)));
```

But result displaying in other **java swing Components** like `jTextpane` or `jLabel` or `jTextArea` does not get any typing effect.

```
// to display in jTextPane
       jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+String.valueOf(CERT[i].charAt(j)));
```

Does anyone help me to display the same typing effect in `jTextarea` as shown in **Output Panel** ?

Comment: Sir,,Please understand my question before marking as down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a `Timer` for doing the typing effect. Something like this:

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //System.out.println("J = " + j);  //for debugging
               // System.out.println("I = " + i);
                if(j >= CERT[i].length()){
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                    jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "\n");

                }

              if(i >= CERT.length) ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
              else{
                  jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + CERT[i].charAt(j));
                  j++;
              }
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

This way I'm thinking the UI thread wont get stuck when you call `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: `jTextPane1.setText(jTextPane1.getText()+"\n");` All GUI updates should be done ***on*** the EDT.

Comment: Great job @user3712476.Thank you.And a small mistake from my code and I will edit it in your answer to get a super effect.

Comment: yeah np also increase thread sleep to 100 and 200. I got better results this way. It seems to go too fast when u run it on another thread.

Comment: Note to readers: This task would be better done using a Swing `Timer`. Please ignore this (fragile) answer.

Comment: Another note to readers: Ive updated my answer per @AndrewThompson 's comment.